# Find count of domains and subdomains in the list of strings using python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, count

Given a list, like so:

```
a = [".com", "google.com" , "maps.google.com", "foo.google.com",
     "bar.google.in", "fine.network.co", "new.network.in"]
```

I need to find the count of strings that has domain names and sub domain names in dictionary format. For example:

```
{'.com': 4, 'google.com': 3, 'maps.google.com': 1, 'foo.google.com': 1,
 'bar.google.in': 1, '.in': 2, '.co': 1, 'google.in': 1 'network.co': 1,
 'fine:network.co': 1, 'bar.google.in': 1, 'network.in': 1, 'new.network.in': 1}
```

My approach is to:

1. loop through list
2. slice the first string till . and now if there is single . it has max 2 names 1 sub domain and other full domain, if it has 2 . , then it has two subdomain and 1 full domain and
3. add the key and value to dictionary and repeat the process

```
aa=["new.com", "google.com" , "maps.google.com", "foo.google.com", "bar.google.in", "fine.network.co", "new.network.in"]

dit={}
j=0
for i in range(len(aa)):
    c = aa[i].split(".")
    for  j in range(len(c)):
         #print(j)
         for k in c:
            #print(k)
             m = "."+ k
             #print(m)
             if m in aa[i]:  
                print(m) 
                kk=aa[i].count(m)
                dit[m]=kk+1
                print(dit)  
             elif aa[i] in aa:
                  print("yes")

         j +=1       #   
    i +=1
```

resulting in the below sample.  i am strugling to add as single dictonary and update the values for the key in the

````
.com
{'.com': 2}
yes
.com
{'.com': 2}
yes
.com
{'.com': 2}
yes
.com
{'.com': 2}
yes
.google
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2}
.com
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2}
yes
.google
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2}
.com
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2}
yes
.google
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2}
.com
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2}
yes
.google
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2}
.com
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2}
yes
.google
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2}
.com
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2}
yes
.google
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2}
.com
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2}
yes
.google
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2}
.in
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2, '.in': 2}
yes
.google
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2, '.in': 2}
.in
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2, '.in': 2}
yes
.google
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2, '.in': 2}
.in
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2, '.in': 2}
yes
.network
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2, '.in': 2, '.network': 2}
.co
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2, '.in': 2, '.network': 2, '.co': 2}
yes
.network
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2, '.in': 2, '.network': 2, '.co': 2}
.co
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2, '.in': 2, '.network': 2, '.co': 2}
yes
.network
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2, '.in': 2, '.network': 2, '.co': 2}
.co
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2, '.in': 2, '.network': 2, '.co': 2}
yes
.network
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2, '.in': 2, '.network': 2, '.co': 2}
.in
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2, '.in': 2, '.network': 2, '.co': 2}
yes
.network
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2, '.in': 2, '.network': 2, '.co': 2}
.in
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2, '.in': 2, '.network': 2, '.co': 2}
yes
.network
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2, '.in': 2, '.network': 2, '.co': 2}
.in
{'.com': 2, '.google': 2, '.in': 2, '.network': 2, '.co': 2}```

 I simply expect the output should be the as simple as :
``` {.com : 4 , google.com:3, maps.google.com:1 , foo.google.com:1 , bar.google.in:1, .in:2, .co:1, google.in:1, network.co:1, fine.network.co:1, bar.google.in: 1, network.in:1, new.network.in:1} ```
````

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a very convoluted way of doing it. Try a simpler approach:

```
domain_list = [".com", "google.com" , "maps.google.com", "foo.google.com", "bar.google.in", "fine.network.co", "new.network.in"]

domain_parts_list = set(domain_list + ["." + d.split(".", i)[-1] for d in domain_list for i in range(1, d.count(".") + 1)])

result = {}
for domain in domain_parts_list:
  result[domain] = len([d for d in domain_list if d.endswith(domain)])

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'.network.in': 1, 'fine.network.co': 1, '.network.co': 1, 
 '.co': 1, 'maps.google.com': 1, '.google.in': 1, 'bar.google.in': 1, 
 'new.network.in': 1, 'google.com': 3, 'foo.google.com': 1, 
 '.google.com': 2, '.com': 4, '.in': 2}
```

Comment: thanks, for list comprehension model,but we are missing the values of
 ```.in :2 .co:1 , .network.in:1 , network.co:1 ``` from the output

Comment: I see. In that case we should generate a set of all possible domain parts. See updated answer.